# Extracting and using street data from MapBox iOS SDK

Tags: mapbox

Is there a way to identify streets and roads on MapBox maps and get information about their shapes, etc?

I am talking about something like this: http://www.playmapscube.com/ The ball follows the paths created by streets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope: the Mapbox iOS SDK's maps are tile-based rasters, so they don't contain street data as much as a representation of data as an image. In [Mapbox GL Cocoa](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-cocoa), it's possible to get at raw data, but it'll require a bit of experimentation, since it's a very new project.